# Pywinauto - How to wait on specific window title changed among windows with equal windows attributes

Tags: pywinauto

In application I create some instances of the same form (all windows attributes besides handle are the same) and work with them independently. During session form changes own title depending on context, I need to wait title changing after certain operations in form.

Next code, don't wait and get window immediately before title changed:

```
w = app.window(handle = handle, title_re = '...', class_name='...')
w.wait('ready', timeout = 2)
```

due to work features of function `find_elements()`:

```
if handle is not None:
    return [backend_obj.element_info_class(handle), ]
```

So, what the best solution for it?

P.S. some forms I need to speed up execution, it's important

Of course I can use next code:

```
def check_state():
    windows = app.windows(title = '...', class_name='...')
    for w in windows:
        if handle == w.handle:
            return(True)
    return(False)

pywinauto.timings.wait_until(5, 0.5, check_state, True)
```

Is it the best solution or probably I skipped something else?

Comment: BTW, do you think method `.wait_property_change(prop=value)` would be useful for wrapper object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, function `timings.wait_until(...)` is good enough for this purpose. Methods `.wait()` and `.wait_not()` are limited to a window specification only. `wait_until` is generic one.

Also search criterion `found_index=i` can be useful in `.window(...)/.child_window(...)` specification.

Comment: `found_index` allows to get certain element by index among found elements, as far as I understand. What the criteria to order found elements?

Comment: It's ordered by the operating system. I suppose it's order of creation.

Comment: Thank you, one question more: why `.windows(...)` doesn't return list of `class WindowSpecification()` instances likes `.window(...)/.child_window(...)`? I was confused it

Comment: Historical reason. WindowSpecification assumes unambiguous search criteria, so plural noun shouldn’t be associated with WindowSpecification. But we’re planning to add .find_all() and rename .wrapper_object() to .find() in future releases. child_window() will have short alias .by(). Any other suggestions can be considered.